# Add the note not to post images of code

Tags: feature-request, images

#### Request

A lot of new users post images of code/data/errors. Probably we should add a note when pasting/uploading an image?

#### Reproduce

Start writing a question/answer/discussion and paste/upload an image.

#### How to solve

It should look somehow like this:
[image]

Probably add this div:

```html
<div class="flex--item fs-body2">Do not post images of code/data/errors.  
<a href="//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551">Learn more</a></div>
```

My proposition is to add it in the div with class `flex--item d-flex gs8 gsy fd-column js-cta-container` (you will see it when uploading the image). Here's the JS which you can run in DevTools to better understand where it should be:

```js
document.querySelector(".flex--item.d-flex.gs8.gsy.fd-column.js-cta-container");
```

Comment: As a small note, links like that should really be linking to a help center page, not to a question.

Comment: @Cerbrus meta has become a defacto equivalent to the help center. Optimally, the meta FAQ would be fully integrated into the help center, but we don't live in an optimal world

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike are there any more examples where a built-in message like that actually links to a question?